# Is there an alternative to async:false in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am getting Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.
I have looked into this post but couldnt find anything to suit my need.

[alternative to async: false ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090764/alternative-to-async-false-ajax)

```
$(docucment).ready(function(){

var obj=AppendFileList(10); 
 $.each(obj.Table, function (key, value) {
             //some code to do some task                                           
   });

});




function AppendFileList(lotid) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "XYZ/GetAttachements",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ LotId: lotid, GUID: $('#hidnuniqueid').val() }), // LotId: arr1[1],
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data, status) {
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
                        console.log(obj);
                        return obj;

                    },
                    failure: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);

                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log(data.Message);
                    }
                });

            }
```

I do not want to keep ajax() method outside within a separate function as i have shown in my example so that I dont have to write ajax call again and again. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the logic which relies on the result of the AJAX request should go in the `success` callback. To achieve this, you can pass an anonymous function to your `AppendFileList()` function. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    AppendFileList(10, function(data) { // data = the JSON retrieved
        $.each(obj.Table, function (key, value) {
            // some code to do some task                                           
        });
    }); 
});

function AppendFileList(lotid, callbackFn) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "XYZ/GetAttachements",
        data: { 
            LotId: lotid, 
            GUID: $('#hidnuniqueid').val() 
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, status) {
            callbackFn(data); // use your callback here, passing it the retrieved data
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.Message);
        }
    });
}
```

Note that you don't need to use `JSON.stringify` to send the `data` or deserialise the response as jQuery will automatically do this for you and that the `$.ajax()` method has no `failure` property in its settings.

Comment: Your solution is working fine. But I can not make it work without parsing it to Json .. `callbackFn(jQuery.parseJSON(data.d));`  

I return data from server using newtonsoft dll `return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.Indented);` 

I lack experience. Perhaps you can help me do this in a better way.