# Can't return variable from Ajax function

Tags: ajax, asynchronous

I've been struggling for a while with an Ajax function and despite the different attempts I'm can't get my variable usable in the reste of the code.

```
load_table('table1');

function load_table(table_name){
  $('#'+table_name).DataTable( {
    "ajax": {
      "url": "./admin_functions.php",
        "type": "POST",
        "dataType": 'json'
    },
    "drawCallback": function() {
      switch(table_name) {
        case 'table1':
          var array_loop = [[1, 1],[2, 2]];
         break;
        case 'table2':
          var policy_dropdown_json = {};
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
              url: "./admin_functions.php",
              data: { action: 'get_dropdown',
                "table_name": 'support'
               },
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(result) {
                 policy_dropdown_json = JSON.stringify(result);
                 console.log(policy_dropdown_json); // Result OK. Contains JSON string
              }
         });

          console.log(policy_dropdown_json); // Result not OK. Contains empty object
          var array_loop = [[1, 1,],[2, 2, policy_dropdown_json]];
        break;
        default:
          var array_loop = [[1, 1,],[2, 2],[3, 3]];
      }

      $('#'+table_name).Tabledit({
        "url": "./admin_functions.php?table_name="+table_name,
        columns: {
          identifier: [0, 'id'],
          editable: array_loop
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I need to use `policy_dropdown_json` outside the Ajax function but it is always empty. I understand that it is an async call and adding `async: false` fixes it but it is deprecated.

I have tried putting the Ajax code in a separate function or use `Promises` (which I'm not familiar with) but it doesn't help. For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090764/alternative-to-async-false-ajax) or [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83426/rewriting-this-function-to-use-promises-instead-of-async-false).

I'm using Datatables and Tabledit plugins.

`policy_dropdown_json` is supposed to be a JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to use it like this:

```
load_table('table1');

function load_table(table_name) {
    $('#' + table_name).DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "./admin_functions.php",
            "type": "POST",
            "dataType": 'json'
        },
        "drawCallback": function() {
            switch (table_name) {
                case 'table1':
                    var array_loop = [
                        [1, 1],
                        [2, 2]
                    ];
                    break;
                case 'table2':
                    var policy_dropdown_json = {};
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "./admin_functions.php",
                        data: {
                            action: 'get_dropdown',
                            "table_name": 'support'
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(result) {
                            policy_dropdown_json = JSON.stringify(result);
                            console.log(policy_dropdown_json); // Result OK. Contains JSON string
                            var array_loop = [
                                [1, 1, ],
                                [2, 2, policy_dropdown_json]
                            ];

                            $('#' + table_name).Tabledit({
                                "url": "./admin_functions.php?table_name=" + table_name,
                                columns: {
                                    identifier: [0, 'id'],
                                    editable: array_loop
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    return; //Ajax will spawn off separately and hit this return before the ajax request ends. Once the ajax request is complete, it will use the code inside the success parameter.
                    console.log(policy_dropdown_json); // Result not OK. Contains empty object
                    var array_loop = [
                        [1, 1, ],
                        [2, 2, policy_dropdown_json]
                    ];
                    break;
                default:
                    var array_loop = [
                        [1, 1, ],
                        [2, 2],
                        [3, 3]
                    ];
            }

            $('#' + table_name).Tabledit({
                "url": "./admin_functions.php?table_name=" + table_name,
                columns: {
                    identifier: [0, 'id'],
                    editable: array_loop
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

You'll also notice that once the ajax is complete, the table is created and policy_dropdown_json is correct and array_loop is also correct. Until the ajax completes, neither of these 2 variables are set to the right data.

Comment: The problem remains with the `array_lopp` in the last row of code, which stays undefined

Comment: Did you try my code? If you execute as is, the code below default should never be hit when executing table2

Comment: Also, I forgot to ask if table1 was the problem. If so, define array_loop before the switch statement. Call car array_loop=[] before the switch and remove the var from the other definitions, so only 1 var array_loop is in the code.

Comment: Car is typo for var

Comment: Will try tomorrow morning and let you know. Thanks